# textarea wrap hard add new line to the wrapped word

Tags: php, html, textarea, word-wrap

I have a script that print the content of a file in a textarea in order to make changes to the content of the file and then update it.

```
$file_content = file_get_contents($filename);
if (isset($_POST['text']))
    file_put_contents($filename, $_POST['text']);

<textarea name="text" wrap="hard">
    echo htmlspecialchars($file_content, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
</textarea>
```

In order to make "better looking" the textarea edit form I added the `wrap="hard"` attribute so the content of the file can be viewed without scrolling horizontally.

The problem of this attribute is that when it word wrap a sentence which is in one line: after updated the file using the form, the word wrap is effective also in the file content, adding a new line `\n` in the wrapped sentence.

There's any way to avoid this?

Comment: Let's see you set up this issue in a demo.  We want to see some sample data and what you wish as the desired output.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you'll be able to differentiate between user newlines and automated newlines.  I mean even if you `onsubmit()` remove the `wrap` attribute, if there is any adjustment, I don't think there would be sufficient awareness to repair the data.

Comment: Why are you using hard wrap? That specifically adds newlines to the submitted data when it hits the textarea's column width. Is there any reason you can't do this with `wrap="soft"`? Make the textarea reasonably large enough, then just live with people who want their data on a single line.

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden;` would probably work if you're looking for a CSS method during outputting to browser. In either case, you're best handling this with CSS than messing with the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll recommend `style="resize: vertical;` and just make sure that you are as generous as possible with your `cols` and `rows` attributes.

This will avoid generating unwanted newlines and eliminate the possibility of horizontal scrolling.

I did a quick/dirty test at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_textarea_wrap

As @Funk commented, `overflow-x: hidden` is another valid styling technique.

But hey, the default behavior of a textarea is to wrap this for you anyhow.  Do you have other stylings applied to your element that you haven't told us about?  Is the textarea confined by other elements?